# Detecting → Symbol in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm working on a script using Python 3.6.0 to convert output from a meter to an xlsx file. At the end of the input file is a → symbol that signifies the end of the file.

I want to specifically skip the current line when I detect the → symbol. (It is possible for me to append multiple files together before I convert them and therefore have multiple → symbols denoting the ends of the original files.)

Notepad++ detects the formatting as <s>UTF-8</s> ANSI , but I can't get the if statement in my Python code to detect the arrow. The → also shows itself plainly in plain old Notepad.

My most recent iteration was this attempt:

```
elif '\u+2192' in line:
```

which fails to detect the right arrow. The same thing happens attempting it this way:

```
elif '→' in line:
```

How can I detect this one character?

EDIT: Incase it matters, the file I'm reading in is a .log file.

EDIT: More code/data to help troubleshoot.

Here is a snippet at the end of my log file:

```
TIM= 15:24:47
TODAY -0.0687869 m3
→
```

***Note: When I copy and paste the text from Notepad it does not paste the arrow.

Here is how I'm reading through the lines of the file:

```
with open(datafile, 'r') as df:
    for line in df:
```

Comment: works for me: `'→' in  'line → line'` returns `True`. So in which way it "fails" for you?

Comment: Hmm, for me the line never evaluates to True. It skips over that case.

Comment: Python version?

Comment: In this case it matters if you are using Python 2 or Python 3.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.0

Comment: Regardless of the Python version, the `+` is a problem. The correct syntax is `u'\u2192'`.

Comment: so could you put more code into the question? Because the error is not obviously in this line, as I stated in my first comment.

Comment: Are you reading the file using the correct charset/encoding?  What are the actual bytes contained in the file and what is the actual value of your variable `line`?

Comment: Python interprets a file as being ISO-8859-encoded by default, regardless of the encoding used to create it.

Comment: @chepner That's not true. The encoding used is platform dependent, and is the same as what is returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). Why would it default to ISO-8859? That would be rather strange.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I made the same mistake warned about here:https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html.

Comment: @Ramrod You need to specify the encoding when opening the file.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).  Example: `open(datafile, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: You guys I made a big mistake (I read the wrong encoding on the wrong window.) The log file isn't in UTF-8. When I try to open using UTF-8 encoding as @dsh suggested python throws an error, when I use ANSI encoding it opens. So I guess I need to write the elif for ANSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right arrow is actually a control-Z, as shown in [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). Control-Z is accepted by many Windows programs as the end-of-file marker for text files, for historical reasons. If you look for character `\x1a` you'll find it.

If you open the file in Text mode, it should strip that character automatically.

Comment: That solved the issue by doing the following:

   `if 'x1a' in line:`

Answer (score 3):

It's `'\u2192'` not `'\u+2192'`. Also remember to specify the correct encoding.

You can also use  `\x` , `\U` , or `\N`, for example `'\N{RIGHTWARDS ARROW}'`.

According to PEP8:

> In the standard library, non-default encodings should be used only for
>   test purposes or when a comment or docstring needs to mention an
>   author name that contains non-ASCII characters; otherwise, using \x ,
>   \u , \U , or \N escapes is the preferred way to include non-ASCII data
>   in string literals.